# mv multiple files on Linux vs. on Mac

Tags: bash, zsh, syntax

To move multiple files on Linux, one could use:

```
mv -t DESTINATION file1 file2
```

Whereas on macOS it is

```
mv file1 file2 DESTINATION
```

Why is this difference? Is this a Bash vs. Zsh thing, or older vs. newer syntax, or what?

Comment: FWIW, `zsh`'s `mv` builtin, which you can enable with `zmodload zsh/files` doesn't support a `-t` option whether that's on macOS or GNU/Linux-based OSes (btw "Linux" (a kernel) or "Mac" (a (PC-based these days) hardware platform) are irrelevant here). Note zsh (like bash) existed long before MacOS/X (or even Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has nothing to do with the shell (bash vs zsh), it is simply different implementations of `mv`. A Linux machine will most likely have [GNU `mv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html) since Linux machines tend to be built using GNU utilities. MacOS, on the other hand, ships with [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) utilities instead. This means that many common command line utilities behave differently since they are different implementations designed to do the same thing, but with different tweaks.

So not older vs newer, simply tools designed to do the same thing, but written by different people who made different design choices. It's the same idea as a car: all cars will have a way to steer, break, accelerate etc. However, different car manufacturers will add different things (air conditioning, radio, heated seats or whatever) which will be designed in different ways. They're still all cars, just like both the GNU and BSD `mv` are still `mv`s, but they have their own quirks and features beyond the basic functionality.

---

Note that the standard `mv file1 file2 dir/` will work with Linux `mv` just as well as with Mac's. if you are not sure what implementation you're using, just use the `mv file1 file2 dir/` syntax and it will work with any `mv`.

Answer (score 3):

The first example of `mv` uses the [GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html) `-t` (`--target-directory`), and has a [particular rationale](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Target-directory.html).

Your second example is the [standard POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) solution and will work for every platform offering `mv` (including those systems using the GNU implementation of `mv`).

If you are using the second version and want to guarantee that the target is a directory that already exists, suffix it with `/`. The `mv` will either succeed cleanly or fail with an error. (Without the trailing `/`, if the target does not exist or is not a directory then the `mv` will act simply as a rename.)